# Adding custom gesture recognizer to view in Xcode Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, uigesturerecognizer

Can I use Interface Builder (e.g. in Xcode 6.1.1) for adding an `UIGestureRecognizer` to a view?

I was thinking of a procedure similar to dragging a  gesture recognizer from the Object Library onto the view and then changing its class to a custom class in Identify Inspector. However, the object library only contains specific gesture recognizers (`UITapGestureRecognizer`, etc.) but not the generic `UIGestureRecognizer` (nor its superclass `NSObject`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it by dragging the generic Object into the Storyboard, going to the Identity inspector and typing in `UIGestureRecognizer` as the class. Since Storyboard does not have direct support for the `UIGestureRecognizer` class, it won't be able to do much, except being referenced as an outlet.
[image]

Comment: Ah, I missed the (generic) Object in that list.

Comment: It's very convenient, you can add an object of any class to IB that way :)

Comment: Unfortunately it is apparently not even possible to now wire up this gesture recognizer with a view also in IB, just to reference it as an outlet as you say.

Comment: Yeah, only IB-supported objects get that special treatment. Should be easy to do in Swift/Obj-C though, so it's probably better to just do all of this programmatically.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can now add a Gesture Recognizer directly from the Object Library. Type, "gesture" and you can add Tap Gesture Recognizer, for example.